# Add Textbox value to table using jQuery for postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

have tried searching for this with no success. I want to be able to add urls to a table from textbox values then return these to a MVC controller POST action. Have tried the below but the submit click is triggering the post back to the server rather than executing the jquery code.

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="text" name="input" id="Text1"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
}

<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table" id="table1">
         <tr>
            <th>Site</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>www.example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("WebDriver", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Complete" id="complete" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var val1 = $('input[id="Text1"]').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < val1; i++) {
            $('table[id="table1"]')
                .append(' <tr class="row">' + val1 + '</tr>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing in your code makes any sense. Your have 2 forms, the first with a textbox and a submit button but you dont want to submit it. The second form has a submit button, but nothing to submit. You script tries to loop through the text in the textbox whicj is not a collection. Then all it does is add some text to a table (not a control) so there is nothing will ever be posted.

Comment: My best guess is that you want to dynamically build a collection of websites and post back the whole collection (in which case your code is all wrong). If that the case, please update your question with a better explanation and I can give you a solution

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your case is that you are reloading the page when you fire the "click" event. This is why you have to **prevent the default behaviour** of the submit button, this way :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit').click(function(e){
    //this prevents the form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    //this updates the table info 
    var val1 = $('input[id="Text1"]').val();
    $('#table1').html( $('#table1').html()+' <tr class="row"><td>' + val1 + '</td></tr>');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // this is how to stop the form submitting
  var val1 = $('#Text1').val();  // us an id selector - it is much better performance
  if (val1 != '') { // check if textbox was empty (not sure what your loop did)
    $('#table1').append('<tr class="row"><td>' + val1 + '</td></tr>');  //apend new row to table
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="./" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="input" id="Text1"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table" id="table1">
         <tr>
            <th>Site</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>www.example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead change the "submit" button to just a "button", and on your click handler, you can submit the form after processing if needed. You should also add an ID to your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
   <input type="text" name="input" id="Text1"/>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var val1 = $('input[id="Text1"]').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < val1; i++) {
            $('table[id="table1"]')
                .append(' <tr class="row">' + val1 + '</tr>');
        }
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```